# Unable to switch to classic application for adding listener to docusign connect

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add a docusign connect listener but when I click on switch to classic application, it takes me back to new application landing page. I have a professional account. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your free developer sandbox account to test DocuSign Connect, not your paid production account.  If you do an API Integration that uses Connect and you want to enable in production environment then you need go through DocuSign's API Certification Process.  Login to your dev account and the switch back to Classic will work.

To create a free dev sandbox check out the home page:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center

And see the Go Live section for information regarding API Certification:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/overview